# Activity derives from native class (.so probably without JNISUPPORT)

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Following task: "Create an Activity that derives from the GtfNativeActivity class."
I have a libGtfNativeActivity.so file.

Do i get it right, that "derives" means something like "Activity extends GtfNativeActivity"?
How can i "include" this GtfNativeActivity class?

What i've done so far is the following:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("GtfNativeActivity");
}
```

Should the .so files been built exclusively with NDK? I get the following in logcat:

> 01-02 00:52:52.640: D/dalvikvm(3831): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.example.custom_apk/lib/libGtfNativeActivity.so 0x410a9e80
>
> 01-02 00:52:52.640: D/dalvikvm(3831): Added shared lib /data/data/com.example.custom_apk/lib/libGtfNativeActivity.so 0x410a9e80
>
> 01-02 00:52:52.640: D/dalvikvm(3831): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.example.custom_apk/lib/libGtfNativeActivity.so 0x410a9e80, skipping init

Is it possible to "include" such files, even if they're not written for java support
(JNISUPPORT)?

Thanks in advance.
Chris

Comment: do you have `libGtfNativeActivity.so` inside `libs/armeabi` ?

Comment: initially yes, but then added native support to the eclipse project and i can't say where it's gone